# Setting page background-color

Tags: html, css

Im trying to set a page background-color in desktop.

Tried.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
webpage
</title>
</head>
<body style="background- 
color:black;text- 
align:center">
welcome to my page
</body></html>
```

And

```
#doc3 {
margin: auto 10px;
width: auto;
height: 2000px;
background-color: yellow;
```

}

And

```
 @media (min-width: 768px){ 
 body, html.page-id-28 
 {background-color:green 
 !important;height: 2000px;

 }}
```

And

```
@media (min-width: 768px){ 
body.page-id-28 {background- 
color:black;
}}
```

And

```
@media (min-width: 768px){ 
body, html.page-id-28 
{background-color:black 
!important;}}
```

Nothing.

[here](https://4309.co.uk)

The page flashes once, and then reverts to white. At best I've managed to change half the body color, but not whole thing.

Comment: Seems like you are using a parallax element which is overriding the page background. Try to overwrite `.parallax-window { background: your-color; }`

Comment: Right first time. Very very very very well done. Up vote for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into the head of the page like so

```html
<head>
    <title>webpage</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Anything you add into this style block will apply to everything in the body of the whole document. It is better to do this than put it inside the body tag as this will go right to the edge of the screen and it is easier to read.